# how to host svn server on my computer?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN Server and I want to create an internet facing repository on my computer but I can't seem to get it right. I created the repository, disabled https, and I'm trying to access the server through:

> svn://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/svn/repo/trunk
>   or
>   http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/svn/repo/trunk

but each case gives me an error.

In the case of svn protocol:

> Can't connect to host
>   'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx': No connection could
>   be made because the  target machine
>   actively refused it.

And in the http case:

> OPTIONS of
>   'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/svn/repo':
>   could not connect to server
>   (http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080)

What am I missing?
Do I need to configure an Apache server or something like that in order to be able to make the server public?

Update: I'm running on Windows 7, windows firewall is disabled, no other firewall is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to configure Apache to serve out the SVN repository.  Example configuration:

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /usr/local/subversion/repos
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-file
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Comment: but doesn't VisualSVN Server already configure apache to do this?

Answer (score -1):

personally i wouldn't host your own on your own server , just from my own 30 Years experience after many years of trying to do just that with the barrage of  constantly having my machines hacked all the time after Firewall intrusions and cleaning up holes constantly and writing and running tons of Cleanup scripts, just not worth the time and effort anymore. just find a free host on the net and go with that. trust me you'll get more code written that way .